# The old parameter syntax `{param}` is no longer supported

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I have tried to write data to neo4j with the below code:

```js
  var express = require('express');
  var path = require('path'); 
  var logger= require('morgan');
  var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
  var neo4j= require('neo4j-driver');

  var app=express(); 

  //view Engine:
  app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(logger('dev'));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
  var driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost',neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j','5141'));
  var session = driver.session();

  app.get('/',function(req, res){
    session
        .run('MATCH(n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 25')
        .then(function(result){
            var movieArr = [];
                result.records.forEach(function(record){
                movieArr.push({
                    id: record._fields[0].identity.low,
                    title: record._fields[0].properties.title, 
                    year: record._fields[0].properties.year
                    
                });
            });
            session
                .run('MATCH(n:Actor) RETURN n LIMIT 25')
                .then(function(result2)
                {
                    var actorArr = [];
                    result2.records.forEach(function(record){
                        actorArr.push({
                            id: record._fields[0].identity.low,
                            name: record._fields[0].properties.name, 
                        })

                    });
                    res.render('index',{
                        movies: movieArr,
                        actors: actorArr

                    });
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
           
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
  });
  app.post('/movie/add',function(req,res){
    var title=req.body.title;
    var year=req.body.year;

    session
        .run('CREATE(n:Movie{title:{titleParam},year:{yearParam}}) RETURN n.title'   
            {titleParam:title,yearParam:year})
        .then(function(result){
            res.redirect('/');
            session.close();
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
                });

    res.redirect('/');
  });
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Server started on port 3000 ');

  module.exports= app;
```

But I keep getting the below error in the terminal:

```
Neo4jError: The old parameter syntax `{param}` is no longer supported. Please use `$param`   
            instead (line 1, column 22 (offset: 21))
            "CREATE(n:Movie{title:{titleParam},year:{yearParam}}) RETURN n.title"
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: If it asks you to write `$param` instead of `{param}`, why don't you just do that?

Comment: I initially did that and it gave below error, so I asked the question.                                         Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: because you're redirecting multiple times in your code

Comment: remove one redirect `res.redirect('/');` from `/movie/add` route.

Comment: Thanks Rifat, but after removing it, it gives below error. Neo4jError: The old parameter syntax `{param}` is no longer supported. Please use `$param` instead (line 1, column 22 (offset: 21))
"CREATE(n:Movie{title:{titleParam},year:{yearParam}}) RETURN n.title"

Comment: Now you change `{param}` to `$param` and see

Comment: I have already done that! there is no change. seems new version of neo4j does not support {param} but I don't see any change after changing it